# After passing the value in the input tag to another section, I can't edit that inputs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing a value from one input tag to another input tag, which are in different independent sections. And after passing the value, I can't edit the input to which I passed the value. Here is the error:

**You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.**

I get the values, but I can't edit the inputs!

Here is code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StartingSection } from './components/StartingSection';
import { CustomizerSection } from './components/CustomizerSection';

function App() {
  const [checkSection, setSection] = useState(false);
  const showCustomizerSection = () => setSection(true);

  const [Width, setWidth] = useState();
  const [Length, setLength] = useState();
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {checkSection ? 
            <CustomizerSection 
              Width={Width} 
              Length={Length}
            /> 
          : 
            <StartingSection 
              Width={Width}
              setWidth={setWidth}
              Length={Length}
              setLength={setLength}
              onClick={showCustomizerSection}  
            />
          }
    </div>
  );
```

StartingSection.jsx

```
export function StartingSection({onClick, Width, setWidth, Length, setLength}) {
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="number" value={Width || ''} onChange={event => setWidth(event.target.value)} />
            <input type="number" value={Length || ''} onChange={event => setLength(event.target.value)} />
            <button className="button w-100" onClick={onClick}>Continue</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CustomizerSection.jsx

I pass values to this section, and at this point the error that I indicated above occurs.

```
export function CustomizerSection({Width, Length}) {
    
    return(
        <div>         
           <input type="number" value={Width} /> <=== this is where I pass the value
           <input type="number" value={Length} /> <=== this is where I pass the value
        </div>
    )
}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like the error message is correctly identifying the situation. You are binding a value for `Width` for example, but you are not allowing anything to change `Width` once it is set.

I don't see where you are using `setSection`, but it looks as if once `StartingSection` is used, then `CustomizerSection` is displayed. However, once `CustomizerSection` is displayed it cannot make use of `setWidth` or `setLength` in order to change the values. This causes the situation where you get a read only textbox (due to one-way binding of the values).

If you would like to use the `StartingSection` as initial values and then change them, you need to manage separate state for the new `CustomizerSection` values:

```
function App() {
  const [checkSection, setSection] = useState(false);
  const showCustomizerSection = () => setSection(true);

  const [Width, setWidth] = useState();
  const [Length, setLength] = useState();

  const [customizedWidth, setCustomizedWidth] = useState(Width);
  const [customizedLength, setCustomizedLength] = useState(Length);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {checkSection ? 
            <CustomizerSection 
              Width={customizedWidth}
              setWidth={setCustomizedWidth}
              Length={customizedLength}
              setLength={setCustomizedLength}
            /> 
          : 
            <StartingSection 
              Width={Width}
              setWidth={setWidth}
              Length={Length}
              setLength={setLength}
              onClick={showCustomizerSection}  
            />
          }
    </div>
  );
```

Changes to `CustomizerSection`:

```
export function CustomizerSection({Width, Length, setWidth, setLength}) {
    
    return(
        <div>         
           <input type="number" value={Width} onChange={event => setWidth(event.target.value)} /> 
           <input type="number" value={Length} onChange={event => setHeight(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, I assumed I had to do with onChange. Thanks!